# Android Web Service Client Using JAX-WS

Tags: android, web-services, jax-ws

I have gone through a complete example of creating a web service and a web service console client using JAX-WS and I created them successfully. Now I'm trying to create an android web service client, but It doesn't seem to work for android. I added the JRE System Library for Java SE 6 in the android project, since it includes the JAX-WS API, and still it didn't work.

I'm currently looking into the Ksoap2-android library, but still wonder why can't I use JAX-WS for creating the android web service?! I thought android was built on java; therefore, I can use any existing java library to build my android apps. I previously used the java api for xml processing JAXP to parse XML files on android and it worked. Why isn't this the same case with JAX-WS?

Comment: Android Java Machine doesn't implement JAX-WS specification. That's why!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this page: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-android/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Well a direct solution:

Add dependency to Gradle (app)

```
compile "javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.12"
```